# Is the Red Cross involved yet in checking up on prisoners of war in Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, rules-of-war, ngos, geneva-convention

Is the Red Cross involved yet in checking up on prisoners of war in Ukraine? I don't see it mentioned [here](https://www.icrc.org/en/where-we-work/europe-central-asia/ukraine) or [here](https://www.icrc.org/en/document/ukraine-crisis-statement-florence-gillette-head-icrc-delegation-kyiv).

Comment: I liked your first sentence better as title, the title was just a list of keywords. Currently the question only asks a yes/no question. Maybe it would be more useful to ask for the current amount of checking for POWs, which would be more quantitative. Also, there might be other trusted organizations besides the Red Cross (I don't know). Finally, what is the connection to politics? Is the Red Cross maybe denied access to POWs? Or is it "just" a history question.

Comment: @Trilarion [The Red Cross has a unique position under the Geneva Conventions. As a completely neutral and independent organization, the International Committee of the Red Cross (ICRC) can act as an impartial and neutral instrument of humanitarian protection during armed conflicts.](https://www.redcross.ca/how-we-help/international-humanitarian-law/what-is-international-humanitarian-law/geneva-conventions-other-treaties-and-conventions)

Comment: [President of the International Committee of the Red Cross arrives in Ukraine
News release 16 March 2022](https://www.icrc.org/en/document/president-international-committee-red-cross-arrives-ukraine)

Comment: https://www.icrc.org/en/document/russia-ukraine-international-armed-conflict-new-visits-prisoners-war-bring-much-awaited